# New SAN causes HTTP 414 error

Tags: iis-7.5, storage-area-network, dfs

We have a IIS virtual directory (/Upload) mapped to a DFS share, which resides on a SAN. The DFS share was moved from SAN A to SAN B and since then if we try to access any content via the virtual directory, we get the error: HTTP Error 414.0 - The page was not displayed because the Request URI is too long.

We have tried different DFS shares and also accessing the SAN directly via its network name, but neither have worked.

We are able to browse the DFS share via Windows Explorer from the servers (2 live, 1 dev, all Windows 2008 R2).

We are using a 3rd party module for image resizing, http://imageresizing.net/, if we point to a image that is in the virtual directory it will return it, e.g. /upload/test.jpg.ashx?width=100, where as /upload/test.jpg will return the above error.

I think the error message is misleading and we have done a failed request tracing and the error logged is:

ModuleName: IIS Web Core
Notification: 2 
HttpStatus: 414 
HttpReason: URL Too Long 
HttpSubStatus: 0 
ErrorCode: 2147942487 
ConfigExceptionInfo
Notification: AUTHENTICATE_REQUEST 
ErrorCode: The parameter is incorrect. (0x80070057)

We have now tried it on a Windows 8 machine, with IIS 8, mapped the virtual directory in the same way and it works.

Comment: Have you tried putting it back to the old configuration to see if the problem goes away?

Comment: how was the data moved?

Comment: also can the account that host this site access the dfs path?

Comment: the host(s) can all access the DFS path, via Windows Explorer.

Comment: I just added an update regarding http://imageresizing.net/, which allows our images to be returned

Comment: my best guess is the account that the imagesizer runs under is diffent then the component that fails.

Comment: The app pool is using a domain account. We have tried Anonymous, Windows (default), Impersonation, all of which won't allow us to serve the images via IIS. But the imageresizer works fine.
The config for the virtual dir hasn't changed between moving from SAN A to B

Comment: hmm wonder if its a smbv3\2\1 issue with the new filer. Are the san heads running different versions of software?

Answer (score 1):

The issue was resolved when the SAN provider finally acknowledged that there is a known issue. They supplied us with a patch, which meant IIS versions <= 7.5 were able to serve files from our SAN.

Comment: It might make sense to name the make and model of SAN so that other could find this question if they had the same problem - i.e. the point of this site.

Answer (score 0):

1. Data was moved using emcopy
2. Yes the user account can access the DFS path and the direct share.